# Angular 4 - angular-tree-component Checkbox is disabled but still clickable on label

Tags: angular, typescript, treeview

I am using https://github.com/500tech/angular-tree-component for my **Angular 4 (v4.3.1)** application. I have disabled checkbox but when i click on label it make checkbox enable/disable Operation.[Hierarchy View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUmk8.png)

**here is html of tree view**

```
<tree-node-content ng-reflect-node="[object Object]" ng-reflect-index="0" ng-reflect-template="[object Object]">
      <!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
    }-->
      <!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-template-outlet": "[object Object]",
      "ng-reflect-ng-outlet-context": "[object Object]"
    }-->
      <div _ngcontent-c11="" class="datatable-checkbox-wrapper">
        <input _ngcontent-c11="" class="input-checkbox change-input-checkbox" type="checkbox" ng-reflect-klass="input-checkbox" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" disabled="">
    <span _ngcontent-c11="" class="input-checkbox-before"></span>
    <span _ngcontent-c11="" class="input-checkbox-after"></span>
  </div>
  <label _ngcontent-c11="" class="form-check-label">some text</label>
</tree-node-content>
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: How are you disabling the checkbox? are you disabling the node or only checkbox?